# how to detect that a user has clicked the notufication and then restart a timer??? android

Tags: android

i have a timer that runs when an activity starts ..say after 10seconds a notification appears stating that the session will expire in 5 sec . if the user clicks on the notification he is redirected to the last page and the timer is restarted ,if not a new notification appears statinf the session has expired ... How to detect if the user has clicked on the notification ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Intent in the `Notification` to communicate back to the `Activity` that the user has clicked it.

When the user selects the notification, Android fires an `Intent` that is defined by the `Notification` (usually to launch an `Activity`, but in your case it should be only to send a message). This should be processed in the `Activity's` [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).